# Error when trying to install cpan install Win32::PerfLib

Tags: windows, perl, cpan

I need to run one Perl script (I have not developped that script). When I tried to run perl.exe the_perl_script.pl, it throws an error about 'Win32::PerfLib'. Hence, I tried to install 'Win32::PerfLib' by using the following command

```
cpan install Win32::PerfLib
```

but I got an error, although I installed gcc.

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.219)
Database was generated on Fri, 18 Mar 2022 08:39:48 GMT
Running install for module 'Win32::PerfLib'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.1)
Checksum for C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\cpan\sources\authors\id\J\JD\JDB\Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.38)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.82)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
Configuring J/JD/JDB/Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Win32::PerfLib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  JDB/Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz
  C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for J/JD/JDB/Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20210123)
cp PerfLib.pm blib\lib\Win32\PerfLib.pm
AutoSplitting blib\lib\Win32\PerfLib.pm (blib\lib\auto\Win32\PerfLib)
Running Mkbootstrap for PerfLib ()
"C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 "PerfLib.bs"
"C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- PerfLib.bs blib\arch\auto\Win32\PerfLib\PerfLib.bs 644
"C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\lib\ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap -typemap C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\cpan\build\Win32-PerfLib-0.07-8\typemap  PerfLib.xs > PerfLib.xsc
"C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- PerfLib.xsc PerfLib.c
gcc -c   -DWIN32 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.07\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.07\"  "-IC:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\lib\CORE"   PerfLib.c
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
gmake: *** [Makefile:330: PerfLib.o] Error 1
  JDB/Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz
  C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\c\bin\gmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Win32::PerfLib'.

C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin>cpan install Win32::PerfLib
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.219)
Database was generated on Fri, 18 Mar 2022 08:39:48 GMT
Running install for module 'Win32::PerfLib'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.1)
Checksum for C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\cpan\sources\authors\id\J\JD\JDB\Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.38)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.82)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
Configuring J/JD/JDB/Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Win32::PerfLib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  JDB/Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz
  C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for J/JD/JDB/Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20210123)
cp PerfLib.pm blib\lib\Win32\PerfLib.pm
AutoSplitting blib\lib\Win32\PerfLib.pm (blib\lib\auto\Win32\PerfLib)
Running Mkbootstrap for PerfLib ()
"C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 "PerfLib.bs"
"C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- PerfLib.bs blib\arch\auto\Win32\PerfLib\PerfLib.bs 644
"C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\lib\ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap -typemap C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\cpan\build\Win32-PerfLib-0.07-9\typemap  PerfLib.xs > PerfLib.xsc
"C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- PerfLib.xsc PerfLib.c
gcc -c   -DWIN32 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.07\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.07\"  "-IC:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\perl\lib\CORE"   PerfLib.c
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
gmake: *** [Makefile:330: PerfLib.o] Error 1
  JDB/Win32-PerfLib-0.07.tar.gz
  C:\AMTServices\docgen2\ennov-amt-remote-client\ennov-docgen-service\script\myperl\c\bin\gmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Win32::PerfLib'.
```

I just retarted my PC and reinstall again, have another error

> gcc -c   -DWIN32 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS
> -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION="0.07" -DXS_VERSION="0.07"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   PerfLib.c In file included from c:\mingw\include\windef.h:269,
> from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:42,
> from PerfLib.xs:2: c:\mingw\include\winnt.h:49:10: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory    49 | #include
> <string.h>
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. gmake: *** [Makefile:330: PerfLib.o] Error 1 FAIL ! Installing Win32::PerfLib
> failed. See C:\Users\nnguyen.cpanm\work\1647607011.15028\build.log
> for details. Retry with --force to force install it.

Comment: The module installs fine on Windows 11, Strawberry Perl version 5.32.1, [here](https://pastebin.com/7Q5U2Vyk)  is my install log. Which version of Windows and which version of perl are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help; I use windows, Strawberry perl v5.32.1. I run without errors before. Just got this error today. I also got the new error which I updated my post (see above). Any idea?

Comment: *"See C:\Users\nnguyen.cpanm\work\1647607011.15028\build.log"* Can you please upload the build file somewhere (e.g. pastebin) and provide a link here?

Comment: There is no `install` command for cpan. It's just `cpan MODULE_NAME`.